# Convert WAB files to something Mac address book can read

Tags: macos, address-book, outlook-express

The other day my PC crashed. I have a automatic backup (which is a life saver) so now I am trying to move all my email and address book files to a Mac computer.

However, it's in .WAB format and Mac's address book won't read that file type.

Is there anyway to convert .WAB to something address book can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple programs you can try out (both for Windows, sorry):

- [Dawn](http://mysite.verizon.net/zakharin/software/Dawn/) will convert your address book from one program's format to another.
- [Address Magic Personal](http://www.connectedsw.com/Overview/57262) - Easily convert email, contacts and calendars between Gmail, Outlook, Lotus Notes and more.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to get on a friend's PC and see if it works..